# How do I change the partition that Windows 7 boots from (the "system" partition)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

(I've searched around but most cases deal with having two hard drives, not two partitions on one hard drive.)

My 1TB hard drive has two partitions: one for Windows XP and one for Windows 7. The Windows XP partition was created first, before the Windows 7 installation. I'm trying to delete my Windows XP partition but I find that I cannot format it from Windows 7 because this partition is still the "system" and "active" partition. I've tried changing the Windows 7 partition to "active" and rebooting, trying to repair the installation with the Windows 7 disc (to add the "system" data to the Windows 7 partition) but that just sent me through a nightmare of "BOOTMGR is missing" and my Windows 7 partition suddenly becoming RAW format, which I just recovered from (dodged a bullet, there).

**My question is:** how would I make my Windows 7 partition the "system" drive, removing the reliance on the Windows XP partition so I could format it?

I have my original Windows 7 installation disc and an Ubuntu 12.04 livecd at my disposal.

My disk management screen:

[image: my disk management screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From XP

Open up cmd and type

```
diskpart
```

and then

```
list partition
```

Make note of the number of the partition that you want to mark as active.

type

```
diskpart
```

and at the diskpart prompt

```
select partition *the partition number you wrote down*
```

at the diskpart prompt

```
active
```

Now use bcdboot.exe to copy the Windows 7 boot files to the new system partition.

```
Bcdboot D:\Windows /c C:
```

Bcdboot copies the required boot environment files for Windows 7 to the C: partition, and creates a new BCD store to boot Windows 7 from the D: partition.

Now The legacy boot files are: NTDETECT.COM, NTLDR, and BOOT.INI. To copy these hidden files from the root directory of the legacy OS partition to the new system partition, execute the following commands:

```
xcopy /h C:\NTDETECT.COM C:
xcopy /h C:\ntldr C:
xcopy /h C:\Boot.ini C:
```

Now reboot to windows 7 to establish the new system partition. This i believe should fic your issue. To see where i got this answer ho here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829686(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_Step1

Since youre not going to dual boot XP and 7 you should not have to do anything after rebooting to windows 7. Then you should be able to delete the XP partition.

Comment: I did what you said, with the BCDboot command as:
`bcdboot D:\Windows /s C:`
from the Windows Recovery Environment command prompt. Upon restart, I got a **BOOTMGR IS MISSING** error, and chose to repair my startup with my Windows 7 disc.

After the repair, I boot into Windows 7 to see that my Windows 7 partition is the system partition and can now format the Windows XP partition.

In other words, this worked. Thanks!

Comment: Your're welcome, glad to see it worked!

Comment: @cojomojo, I'm stuck at the part `diskpart active`. It says ["The `ACTIVE` command can only be used on fixed MBR disks"](http://superuser.com/q/908612/78897). How can we get this to work for GPT?

Comment: Uh, I believe the xcopy cmds are wrong because they copy from C: to C:, don't they?

Answer (score 0):

If your machine list both the operating systems just after the POST check when you start the machine, try the following:

Under system properties, in the "Advanced" tab, choose "Startup and Recovery" option, set windows 7 as a default operating system and ucheck the list the operating systems checkbox, then reboot the machine.

if the the machine does not list the windows 7 after the post and the "Boot Mgr" error still persist, you will have to recover your startup files using the windows 7 disc.